# Find combinations of a two dimensional array

Tags: php

I need some help with generation of combinations, specifically in the store they're the variants of each product, e.g size and colour.

Let's say we have 3 customizable properties of the product:
Colour, Size, and Type.

For this specific product, the following are available of each property:
Color: [red, green], Size: [10, 11, 15], Type: [person]

Now according to the above data, I need to generate **6** combinations, however if we added another type it would increase even more.

I have been drawing on my board for 2 hours now trying to come up with a sane algorithm for this, something that's fast and can deal with thousands of combinations in a matter of seconds.

Take this example:

```
$options = ['Color' => ['Red', 'Green'], 'Size' => ['10', '11', '15'], 'Type' => ['person']];
$combinations = generateCombinations($options);
```

genereateCombinations would then need to generate the following output:

```
[
    ['Color' => 'Red', 'Size' => '10', 'Type' => 'person'],
    ['Color' => 'Red', 'Size' => '11', 'Type' => 'person'],
    ['Color' => 'Red', 'Size' => '15', 'Type' => 'person'],
    ['Color' => 'Green', 'Size' => '10', 'Type' => 'person'],
    ['Color' => 'Green', 'Size' => '11', 'Type' => 'person'],
    ['Color' => 'Green', 'Size' => '15', 'Type' => 'person']
];
```

What algorithm could do this efficiently and with unlimited input "titles"? (of course I'll enforce a limit earlier, but the algorithm **should** be able to do unlimited granted all the resources in the world)

Extending what I mean:
This function also needs to be able to take for example an array with 100 property rows, not just 3, it needs to be able to do this dynamically no matter the number of input rows.

Comment: 3 foreach  do it

Comment: @splash58 Please read the full question before answering...

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that; 3 foreach loops would work fine?

Comment: number system is best example of combination.
you count 000 to 111 in binary is same application as your question.

Comment: No @WillParky93, because it needs to be able to dynamically do it for every row in the $options array, the $options array can have unlimited rows (or titles/properties).

Comment: Heap's algorithm is built for generating permutations but I think you should reconsider your use-case because if you start generating permutations the count goes up fast and it quickly loses any value for the user. After all who's going to read through hundreds or thousands of different variations. It's simply not worth the effort. :-)

Comment: Three `foreach` are enough.

Comment: @SketchyCoder You are wrong. I'm specfically doing this for a customer because this is how he wants it done.

Comment: @splash58 It is is not a duplicate. The algorithm does not apply to this scenario.

Comment: Really? I guess you didn't read my answer yet.

Comment: @axiac You are magic. My bad.

Comment: @Yemiez Customers aren't always right, it's your role to advise them if they want something outrageous. Ask why they want it, how they plan on using it. Perhaps half of the permutations are enough. But this is turning in to spam and an answer has been provided. ;-) Good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three `foreach` loops are enough to generate all combinations, no matter how many entries are in `$options`:

```
function generateCombinations(array $options)
{
    // Start with one combination of length zero
    $all = array(array());

    // On each iteration append all possible values of the new key
    // to all items in $all; generate this way all the combinations
    // one item longer than before
    foreach ($options as $key => $values) {
        // Move all combinations of length N from $all to $current
        $current = $all;
        // Start with an empty list of combinations of length N+1
        $all = array();
        // Combine each combination of length N 
        // with all possible values for the (N+1)th key
        foreach ($current as $one) {
           foreach ($values as $val) {
              // Put each new combination in $all (length N+1)
              $all[] = array_merge($one, array($key => $val));
           }
        }
    }

    return $all;
}


$options = [
    'Color' => ['Red', 'Green'],
    'Size' => ['10', '11', '15'],
    'Type' => ['person'],
    'Answer' => ['Yes', 'No'],
];

$combinations = generateCombinations($options);
echo(count($combinations));
# 12
```

It can probably be slightly improved but, all in all, if you don't know in advance the length of `$options` it does a lot of duplicate iterations. If you know in advance the number of items in `$options` (let's say it is `N`) then `N` nested loops are the fast way to do it.